# Update one UICollectionView when cell is selected in second CollectionView in same ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm working in Swift and have one ViewController serving as the data source and delegate for 2 UICollectionView instances. I want to change which data source is used for collectionView2 based on which item in collectionView1 is selected, and refresh the items displayed in collectionView2 when a new selection is made in collectionView1.

I assume the user's selection will propagate more-or-less like so:

CollectionView1Cell -> ViewController -> CollectionView2

How can the ViewController be alerted that a new selection has been made in the first CollectionView so it can update the cells of the second ViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that you have both of your UICollectionViews with the view controller as delegate and datasource, there's this delegate method for collection views:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

which gives you a collectionView and an IndexPath every time a collection view item is selected, in other others you can do this:

Let's say your first collection view is called **firstCollectionView** you can do as follow

`if collectionView == self.firstCollectionView{ 
   let selectedData = firstCollectionData[indexPath.row]
   //do something with the selected data to affect the secondCollectionView datasource
   self.modifySecondCollectionView(with: selectedData)
   //call the reloadData method for the second collection view in order to display the changes
   self.secondCollectionView.reloadData()
}`

Hope it helps, good luck!

Comment: @iOS_oy I'm glad it did